# Caliburn.Micro Calling a viewmodel from UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I have a AppViewModel, that contains a menu on Top of the Window. On the AppViewModel construct, I'm showing a UserControl. In this UserControl I have a button, that calls another viewmodel (UserControl).

The idea is to keep the menu and working on the content of window. So, I have 1 window and 2 UserControls. This is correct?

How can I call another ViewModel from a button that is inside of a UserControl? Or, I have to call it from the Window? But the button it's inside of the UserControl!

My code:

```
class AppViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private bool _MenuIsVisible;

    public bool MenuIsVisible
    {
        get { return _MenuIsVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (_MenuIsVisible != value)
            {
                _MenuIsVisible = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MenuIsVisible);
            }
        }
    }

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        MenuIsVisible = true;
        _ShowTutorial();
    }

    private void _ShowTutorial()
    {
        ActivateItem(new FirstViewModel());
    }

}



public class FirstViewModel : Screen
{
    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
    }
}
```

On the FirstViewModel I have a button that needs to call SecondViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To navigate from the first ViewModel to the second ViewModel you could have a method in the first ViewModel like this:

```
public void NavigateToSecond()
{
    var conductor = this.Parent as IConductor;
    conductor.ActivateItem(new SecondViewModel());
}
```

The parent refers to the conductor which will take care of navigating for you.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: on SecondViewModel I have a "Back Button", this is correct do the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the TryClose method of the Screen. If you haven't done so already, I highly recommend the excellent documentation here: http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition.

Comment: TryClose worked but it's not showing again the previsous screen :( Do you know why?

Comment: Because you are using Conductor<Object> which keeps only 1 ViewModel in memory. If you want to keep multiple ViewModels alive you'll need to use something like: Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive.